# Check option added by user using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown which has pre filled values in it and a input field for user to add more values to the dropdown, the adding part works fine but there's a check for duplicate entry which somehow is not working right, if I put the nested else in the loop it goes forever and if I move it out, it bypasses the check for duplicate entry. Any suggestions on how can i fix this?

```html
<select id="myDrop">
    <option value="Select" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="Games">Games</option>
    <option value="Movies">Movies</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="userEntry">

<button onclick="addEntry()">Add Entry</button>
<button onclick="myBtn()">Submit</button>

<script>
    function addEntry() {
    
        var dropDown = document.getElementById('myDrop');
        var uEntry = document.getElementById('userEntry');
    
        if (uEntry.value === "") {
            alert("Please enter your option value");
        } else {

            for (var i = 0; i < dropDown.length; i++) {
                if (dropDown[i] === uEntry.value) {
                    alert("Record Exists");
                } else {
                    var uOption = document.createElement('option');
                    uOption.text = uEntry.value;
                    dropDown.add(uOption);
                    alert('Option added');
                }
            }
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check if the value already exists in the dropdown and if found return. the way you are doing right now as you keep adding for else condition everytime, you are getting into an infinite loop.
Also you need to compare `dropdown[i].value` with `uEntry.value` and not the node dropdown[i].

```html
<select id="myDrop">
    <option value="Select" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="Games">Games</option>
    <option value="Movies">Movies</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="userEntry">

<button onclick="addEntry()">Add Entry</button>
<button onclick="myBtn()">Submit</button>

<script>
    function addEntry(){

        var dropDown = document.getElementById('myDrop').children;
        var uEntry = document.getElementById('userEntry');

        if(uEntry.value === ""){
            alert("Please enter your option value");
        }
        else{

        for(var i = 0 ; i< dropDown.length;i++){
            if(dropDown[i].value === uEntry.value){
                alert("Record Exists");
                return;
            }
        }
               var uOption =  document.createElement('option');
                uOption.text = uEntry.value;
                dropDown.add(uOption);
                alert('Option added');
           
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: thanks it worked :), one query out of curiosity wouldn't it work without the return statement?

Comment: it can but then you will have to keep a flag, to not let the statements after the for loop execute in case of a match. right now it returns before them executing as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: you are welcome, if i may ask why did you unaccept it this answer, is there something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should loop all options and after that decide will you add new one or not

```html
<select id="myDrop">
    <option value="Select" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="Games">Games</option>
    <option value="Movies">Movies</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="userEntry">

<button onclick="addEntry()">Add Entry</button>
<button onclick="myBtn()">Submit</button>

<script>
    function addEntry(){

        var dropDown = document.getElementById('myDrop');
        var uEntry = document.getElementById('userEntry');

        if(uEntry.value === ""){
            alert("Please enter your option value");
        }
        else{

          var doAdd = true;
          for(var i = 0 ; i< dropDown.children.length;i++){
            if(dropDown.children[i].value === uEntry.value){
                alert("Record Exists");
                doAdd = false;
            }
          }

          if (doAdd){
                var uOption = document.createElement('option');
                uOption.text = uEntry.value;
                dropDown.add(uOption);
                alert('Option added');
          }

        }
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check directly from drop down, it will go infinity loop, so first get the drop down value in one array, and check the text box value exit or not, if not exit and add all values in the drop down, also checking the case also,

for example : drop down has 'Games', user enter 'games' this is exiting value.

Please try this one.

```html
 <script>
 function addEntry(){

        var dropDown = document.getElementById('myDrop');
        var uEntry = document.getElementById('userEntry');
  var dropDownArray= new Array();
  
  for (i = 0; i < dropDown.options.length; i++) {
     dropDownArray[i] = (dropDown .options[i].value).toLowerCase();
  }
  
        if(uEntry.value === ""){
            alert("Please enter your option value");
        }
       else{

       
            if(dropDownArray.indexOf((uEntry.value).toLowerCase()) != -1){
                alert("Record Exists");
            }
            else{
                var uOption = document.createElement('option');
                uOption.text = uEntry.value;
                dropDown.add(uOption);
                alert('Option added');
            }
      

        }
    }
    </script>
```